# Create a dummy variable column that indicates if a record is in a second dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have some two dataframes, df1 and df2, that take a format like this (reproducible code for data entry at the end):

```r
df1
#>             name instrument
#> 1    John Lennon     guitar
#> 2    Mick Jagger     vocals
#> 3    Ringo Starr      drums
#> 4 Keith Richards     guitar
```

and

```r
df2
#>              name beatles
#> 1     John Lennon       1
#> 2     Ringo Starr       1
#> 3 George Harrison       1
#> 4  Paul McCartney       1
```

I'd like to add a column to df1 that indicates whether a record also in df2 (and equal to 0 if not), so my desired output is:

```r
output
#>             name instrument beatles
#> 1    John Lennon     guitar       1
#> 2    Mick Jagger     vocals       0
#> 3    Ringo Starr      drums       1
#> 4 Keith Richards     guitar       0
```

I've tried `full_join()`, but that pulls across rows in df2 that aren't in df1, which is not what I want. (i.e. The George Harrison and Paul McCartney rows should not be in the output)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2) 

#> Joining, by = "name"
#>              name instrument beatles
#> 1     John Lennon     guitar       1
#> 2     Mick Jagger     vocals      NA
#> 3     Ringo Starr      drums       1
#> 4  Keith Richards     guitar      NA
#> 5 George Harrison       <NA>       1
#> 6  Paul McCartney       <NA>       1
```

Reproducible code below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
         name = c("John Lennon", "Mick Jagger", "Ringo Starr", "Keith Richards"),
   instrument = c("guitar", "vocals", "drums", "guitar")
)

df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                name = c("John Lennon", "Ringo Starr", "George Harrison",
                         "Paul McCartney"),
          beatles = c(1, 1, 1, 1)
       )

library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2)
```

Comment: What you want is `left_join`, but it'll give you `NA`. I don't think you can get `0` in one step using `join` functions only (I'll be happy to be wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left join then mutate to replace the NAs with 0s

```
> library(dplyr)

> output <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, "name") %>% mutate(beatles=ifelse(!is.na(beatles),1,0))
> output
            name instrument beatles
1    John Lennon     guitar       1
2    Mick Jagger     vocals       0
3    Ringo Starr      drums       1
4 Keith Richards     guitar       0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df1$beatles <- ifelse(df1$name %in% df2$name, 1, 0)

            name instrument beatles
1    John Lennon     guitar       1
2    Mick Jagger     vocals       0
3    Ringo Starr      drums       1
4 Keith Richards     guitar       0
```

Or if you have other bands in df2 as well, you could do:

```
df1$beatles <- ifelse(df1$name %in% df2[df2$beatles == 1,]$name, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

A data.table solution for this **left join** would be:

```
df1[df2, on = "name", nomatch = 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```r
library(magrittr)

df1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  name = c("John Lennon", "Mick Jagger", "Ringo Starr", "Keith Richards"),
                  instrument = c("guitar", "vocals", "drums", "guitar"))

df2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                  name = c("John Lennon", "Ringo Starr", "George Harrison",
                           "Paul McCartney"),
                  beatles = c(1, 1, 1, 1))

df1 %>%
  dplyr::left_join(y = df2,
                   by = "name") %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(replace = list(beatles = 0))
#>             name instrument beatles
#> 1    John Lennon     guitar       1
#> 2    Mick Jagger     vocals       0
#> 3    Ringo Starr      drums       1
#> 4 Keith Richards     guitar       0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also `match` the `name` of the two dataframe and specify `nomatch` argument to 0. Assign 1 if the value is greater than 0. The `+` argument in the front converts logical value to integer.

```
df1$beatles <- +(match(df1$name, df2$name, nomatch = 0) > 0)
df1

#            name instrument beatles
#1    John Lennon     guitar       1
#2    Mick Jagger     vocals       0
#3    Ringo Starr      drums       1
#4 Keith Richards     guitar       0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use {powerjoin} and use the `fill` parameter to fill unmatched values with `0`.

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, beatles , by="name", fill = 0)
#>             name instrument beatles
#> 1    John Lennon     guitar       1
#> 2    Mick Jagger     vocals       0
#> 3    Ringo Starr      drums       1
#> 4 Keith Richards     guitar       0
```